# URL of local HTML files wrongly entered in chrome when launched with UFT

Tags: html, hp-uft

I am trying to launch a local HTML file with UFT in google chrome. I am using the below code to launch

```
SystemUtil.Run "chrome.exe","C:\Profiles_Export.html"
```

But the url entered is missing a colon. hence, due to incorrect url, the page is not launched.  I have used the same code in another machine and it is working fine there. so, this doesnt seem like a code issue. Can anyone let me know what is going wrong here.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Did you try double backslash (`\\ `)?

Comment: I assume that you are telling to pass as "C:\\Profile_Export.html". I tried this and it failed. The url was launched as "c//Profiles_Export.html"

Comment: I just tried and it worked for me with no problem (with single backslash, no doubling). This is strange, I don't know what your issue may be.

Comment: It works for me in another machine (windows 11) It just doesnt work in windows 2022 server machine. Not sure if this is some issue with Windows-UFT combination or chrome issue